# SFML.NET DLLNotFoundException with dll.config files in project

Tags: sfml, linux, .net, dll, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run SFML.NET on arch linux and I have two dll.config files in my project called sfmlnet-graphics-2.dll.config and sfmlnet-window-2.dll.config.

sfmlnet-graphics-2.dll.config:

```
    <configuration>
       <dllmap os="linux" dll="csfml-graphics-2" target="libcsfml-graphics.so" />
       <dllmap os="linux" dll="csfml-window-2" target="libcsfml-window.so" />
    </configuration>
```

And sfmlnet-window-2.dll.config:

```
    <configuration>
       <dllmap os="linux" dll="csfml-window-2" target="libcsfml-window.so"/>
    </configuration>
```

So the dll map should work, though I still get this error when I try to run.

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 
    'csfml-graphics-2': The specified module or one of its dependencies 
    could not be found.
     (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
       at SFML.Graphics.RenderWindow.sfRenderWindow_createUnicode(VideoMode 
    Mode, IntPtr Title, Styles Style, ContextSettings& Params)
       at SFML.Graphics.RenderWindow..ctor(VideoMode mode, String title, 
    Styles style, ContextSettings settings)
      at SFML.Graphics.RenderWindow..ctor(VideoMode mode, String title)
      at HelloSharp.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
   /home/kas/Documents/CodeProjects/HelloSharp/Program.cs:line 13
```

This is my Program.cs file:

```
    using System;
    using SFML.Graphics;
    using SFML.Window;

    namespace HelloSharp
    {
        class Program
{

    private static RenderWindow window;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(1280, 720), "Game");
        window.Closed += new EventHandler(OnClosed);
        window.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyEventArgs>(OnKeyPressed);

        while(window.IsOpen) {
            window.DispatchEvents();
            window.Clear();
            window.Display();
        }
    }

    private static void OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        RenderWindow window = (RenderWindow) sender;
        if(e.Code == Keyboard.Key.Escape)
            window.Close();
    }

    private static void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RenderWindow window = (RenderWindow) sender;
        window.Close();
    }
}
    }
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnzhR.jpg) is a picture of my projects layout (where all the files are in relation to each other).

I have the linux version of the csfml .dll's next to the project dll, as well as the linux .so files and the sfmlnet .dll's. I went through a bunch of google searches, tried a bunch of fixes and nothing seems to work. If you take the time to try and help me I appreciate it.
~Kas